# Subdomain www connection is not secure / SSL on VPS with different Domainhost

Tags: dns, ssl-certificate, subdomain, host

following problem:

My webpage example.eu works perfect with SSL connection certified by certbot with apache on ubuntu VPS. If I now enter www.example.eu Firefox says "Your connection is not secure" and "The certificate is only valid for example.eu". The domain is hosted with a different service-provider than the VPS.

First attempt was to direct A-records of the subdomain www.example.eu to the same IP (VPS) as example.eu. Same problem.

Next attempt was to create a CNAME-record for www.example.eu that directs to example.eu. Same problem.

Now I am out of ideas. What can I do?

Thanks in advance and best regards from Germany, Joachim

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I got it now. Problem was with apache/certbot on the VPS:

I checked the virtual host:

```
sudo nano /etc/apache2/sites-available/example.eu.conf
```

it showed
ServerName example.eu
ServerAlias www.example.eu

So no issue here. But certbot seemed to be only configured for example.eu.

```
ls /etc/letsencrypt/live
```

So I had to

```
sudo certbot --apache -d www.example.eu
```

and configure the A-record of the www subdomain to point to the IP of the VPS and: works :)